# How to continue logging user in after anti-forgery token error, extending HandleErrorAtttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am looking to handle the scenario where a user attempts to log-in, while already being logged in.

Currently, this throws the error:

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

I wish to suppress the error, logout the currently logged in user, then continue to login the user now requesting to login.
I am achieving the first 2, but not the the final part of continuing to login the new request.

I am looking to handle this by creating an extension of HandleErrorAttribute, and adding this attribute to my login POST method.

The extended attribute:

```
public class AntiForgeryHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpAntiForgeryException)
        {
            var url = string.Empty;
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath == "/Account/Login" && context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
            {
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                context.HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
                context.HttpContext.ClearError();
                return;
            }
        }

        base.OnException(context);
    }
}
```

My login POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[AntiForgeryHandleErrorAttribute]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

When my code hits the *return* inside **AntiForgeryHandleErrorAttribute**, it never actually reaches my Login POST controller method. Instead, the user is just given a blank screen.

How can I make sure it gets inside the POST method and continues to login the current user?

Comment: Anti-forgery tokens are used to prevent cross-site requests.  If you allow the request to proceed you are potentially allowing a bad request to proceed to login.  See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: Then what is your suggestion for handling this scenario? The user has just submitted the login form. Being redirected back to it in a new request is not going to appear correct to the user and is bad UX. Equally, redirecting them to the landing page for a logged-in user could result in continued browsing of the site under incorrect credentials. Doing nothing gives an error. This needs to be handled. An answer to the original question would be appreciated. A simple "don't do that" leaves me in the exact same situation.